# Some keys stopped working in my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I have Sony VAIO SVS1311F3EW laptop with a very nice keyboard (azerty) but I can't use it since Ubuntu set it off track

The following keys don't work:

- F1, F4, F6, F9, F11
- print screen
- FN, (6 _ |),( ) ]),
- z, d, f, h, j, l,
- %
- (< >)
- SHIFT R
- space
- Right

I tried:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` did not help since my laptop is not listed.
2. Activate "Use system Keyboard Layout" in `ibus-setup` did not help
3. Tried all types of Keyboard input method system in Language Support, but did not help.
4. removed and reinstalled `xserver-xorg-input-all` but did not help as well

Any other suggestions?

```
:~$ setxkbmap -query -v 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      SKIP
layout:     fr,us
variant:    ,
options:    lv3:ralt_switch
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(azerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+fr+us:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
rules:      evdev
model:      SKIP
layout:     fr,us
variant:    ,
options:    lv3:ralt_switchere
```

Comment: Some keys are the typical different keys between AZERTY and QWERTY? And you are on 16.04LTS?

Comment: Which keys are you talking about? (Please clarify by editing your question.)

Comment: I can't use: F1, F4, F6, F9, F11, print screen, FN, (6 _ |), ( ) ]), z ,d,f,h,j,l,%, (< >), SHIFT R, space, Right ... So all my keyboard.

Comment: Ok.. Can you run the command `setxkbmap -query -v 10` and show us what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: The keyboard model seems to not be set, which I think is wrong. I'd suggest that you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` again and select a value. You shouldn't expect to see all laptop models in the list of options. The most commonly used value is `pc105` and I suggest that you try that to start with.

Comment: I did that, but i did not solve my issue.

Comment: Any other suggestions?